How to reorder UV maps in Blender's Data tab?
I'm trying to reorder the UV maps in the Data tab of Blender's Properties panel, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. I've tried clicking and dragging the UV maps, but they won't budge.
Is there a way to reorder the UV maps in the Data tab, or am I missing something obvious? I've searched online and couldn't find a solution.
Blender version: 4.0.2
Steps to reproduce:
Open Blender and create a new project.
Create a mesh object and add multiple UV maps to it.
Go to the Data tab in the Properties panel.
Try to reorder the UV maps by clicking and dragging them.
Expected result: The UV maps should be reorderable in the Data tab.
Actual result: The UV maps cannot be reordered in the Data tab.
I'd appreciate any help or guidance on how to solve this problem!


If you click on the little arrow icon at the bottom left of the list, you can sort UV Maps and other attributes by name. I don't believe there's a way to sort them manually.



Oh thank you so much!
